# Looping through images in python using subprocess Popen and PIPE

Tags: python, subprocess, imagemagick-identify

I have a folder that has a bunch of images. I'm trying to write a python script that will loop through each image and return the width/height and then append it to my dictionary.  A simplified version of my dictionary looks like this:

```
in_metadata = {123: {labels:[1,2]}, 234: {labels:[2,3]}}
```

and what I want is this:

```
in_metadata = {123: {'labels':[1,2], 'bbox':[320,240,640,480]}, 234: {'labels':[2,3], 'bbox':[320,206,640,412]}, ...}
```

where the bbox = [center x, center y, w, h]

When the code goes into the first iteration of the loop, I get:

```
stdout = '640,480'
```

which is what I expect.  However, the second time through the loop I get:

```
stdout = '640,480640,412'
```

The first width and height values aren't being flushed.  Here is my code:

```
command = ['identify', '-format', '%[fx:w],%[fx:h]']
for img_id, img_dict in in_metadata.iteritems():
    if 'bbox' in img_dict:
        continue
    command.append(srcdir + 'images/' + str(img_id) + '.jpg')
    p = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    if len(stderr) != 0:
        continue
    w, h = map(int, stdout.split(','))
    img_dict['bbox'] = [int(w / 2), int(h / 2), w, h]
    stdout.flush()
```

I've all matter of craziness trying to get this to work (p.wait, stdout.flush, etc.) but the buffer does not want to seem to empty.  I know it's something simple, what am I missing?

Thanks.

I'm using python 2.7.12 on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

Each iteration, your `command` is being appended to. I suspect that you don't really want that. Consider this simplified version of your code:

```
labels = 'LABELS'
srcdir = 'SRCDIR/'
in_metadata = {123: {labels:[1,2]}, 234: {labels:[2,3]}}
command = ['identify', '-format', '%[fx:w],%[fx:h]']

for img_id, img_dict in in_metadata.iteritems():
    command.append(srcdir + 'images/' + str(img_id) + '.jpg')
    print command
```

Output:

```
['identify', '-format', '%[fx:w],%[fx:h]', 'SRCDIR/images/234.jpg']
['identify', '-format', '%[fx:w],%[fx:h]', 'SRCDIR/images/234.jpg', 'SRCDIR/images/123.jpg']
```

You probably want something more like this:

```
base_command = ['identify', '-format', '%[fx:w],%[fx:h]']

for img_id, img_dict in in_metadata.iteritems():
    command = base_command + [srcdir + 'images/' + str(img_id) + '.jpg']
    ...
```

Comment: I'm such a bonehead. I've used subprocess quite a few times in the past.  Never have i had so much difficulty.  Thanks for pointing out the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this from bash , can you try setting `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` before running your script?

```
export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=true
```